# Remove Android alert dialog empty space at the top

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I have an Android layout that's used for showing an "about app" alert dialog with a "Close" button. It has a title in **bold** centered, the app version and the developer name. Everything looks fine except that there's a very noticeable margin/padding above the title and I can't remove that empty space.

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="6.0dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center">
      <TextView android:textSize="16.0dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip" android:text="@string/version_text" />
        <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip" android:text="@string/app_version" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:text="@string/about_developer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <Button android:id="@id/close_btn" android:layout_width="110.0dip" android:layout_height="44.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="4.0dip" android:text="@string/about_close" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's what it shows:

[image: about dialog window]

I have tried adding `android:layout_marginTop="-10.0dip"` attribute in many tags and searched SO for a similar issue but I can't find it. I'd be thankful if someone shows me how solve this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try to make your own Dialog with a custom View by using a `DialogFragment` and set this

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Or maybe just try to use a simple `Dialog`, not an `AlertDialog` like this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(theContext);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(yourCustomView);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I was on the half way with the same answer. Well done.

Comment: I am trying to apply your answer and Android Studio tells me that "MainActivity is not an enclosing class" any ideas? Please help.

Comment: I couldn't figure out from where to get context, the code is inside onCreate() which doesn't have one, and there an AboutDialog(Context context) method which is called by the "About app" button, it does have context but when I put your dialog code inside it nothing shows up.

Comment: onCreate() inside an Activity ?
So you can get the context easily by calling getBaseContext()
Did you create the custom View ? (it's a layout on res/layout file)

Comment: I used as a custom view the layout I have in the question, would that work? Calling getBaseContext() from an Activity gives me a "Cannot resolve method" error, but I successfully got context from "MyApplication" class through a static method. Now it crashes with an "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" error caused by the "dialog.show()" line.

Comment: Figured it out, I'm now using getContext() instead and I just had to add "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);" before the existing setContentView() in my code to make it work, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create style for the AlertDialog:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@000000</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

2. Define this style while creating AlertDialog

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(container.getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom);

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout instead (the code below needs to be adjusted to fit your needs, but it gives the general layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="App Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:text="Version 1.0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:text="Developed by Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<Button
    android:text="Close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use a Dialog instead like others have mentioned.

EDIT:

You can try using a custom Dialog instead then using a DialogFragment. To call the Dialog, use this: `new CustomDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mydialog");`

Then create a new class extending DialogFragment, and use something similar to this:

```
public class DonateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
{

private AlertDialog dialog;

public interface CustomDialogListener {
    void buttonClicked();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (!(activity instanceof CustomDialogListener)) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement CustomDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder customDialogMain = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    donateDialogMain.setCancelable(true);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.--YOUR-CUSTOM-DIALOG-LAYOUT-HERE--, null);

    view.findViewById(R.id.close_btn).setOnClickListener(this);

    customDialogMain.setView(view);

    dialog = customDialogMain.show();
    return dialog;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // does something very interesting
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.close_btn:
            ((CustomDialogListener) getActivity()).buttonClicked();
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I adjusted the XML and tried it, issue still persists.

Comment: I added steps to use a Dialog instead, it should get you going. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style direct to style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.UserDialog.AppCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">600dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply this style to the activity class which you wants to set as alert dialog

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.UserDialog.AppCompat"
```

and start activity using Intent like

```
Intent activity= new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);
startActivity(activity);
```