# Remove Xamarin Android alert dialog empty space at the top

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm struggling with the dumbest thing.I want to remove the above space. I found a code in native Android, but was unable to find the same in Xamarin Android ,

Here is the image, showing the empty space:

[image: Showing Space]

Code for Native Android was in Activity on which we are using Dialog Box "dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);"

**Code is below**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
<TextView
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Are you Sure ?"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="You are about to sign out.Do"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="you want to continue ?"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
<GridLayout
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1" >
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/noredbutton"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="No"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/yesgreenbutton"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:text="Yes"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
 </GridLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to paste your popup code so that we can help more

Comment: "I found a code in native Android" - what code?

Comment: Please add the relevant code thanks!

Comment: @Jason - dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    This was in Native Android

Comment: @BhaskaraArani   added !

Comment: @G.hakim added , have a look

Comment: Can you also add the link for that native code you were talking about

Comment: @G.hakim Sure [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751863/remove-android-alert-dialog-empty-space-at-the-top)

Comment: I see that is easy can you add the dialog fragment code and we will get this done

Comment: @G.hakim  Can it not be done with Dialog itself ?

Comment: It can be done actually i am typing the answer as we speak

Comment: Thankyou  , Worked @G.hakim

Comment: @NancyKanwar Sure no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Dialog derectly,

in activity :

```
 //Resource.Layout.dialog is your axml of dialog
 View view = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog,null);
 Button btn1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
 Button btn2 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
 dialog.RequestWindowFeature((int) WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
 dialog.SetContentView(view);
 btn1.Click += delegate { Toast.MakeText(this, "no", ToastLength.Short).Show(); };
 btn2.Click += delegate {Toast.MakeText(this,"yes",ToastLength.Short).Show(); };
 dialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the MainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // some code here
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```